# Using sympy package in python to substitute values into a 10x10 matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using the symbolic package sympy to store a 10X10 antisymmetric matrix in terms of 10 variables. and then at every iteration step, i substitute numerical values into the entries of the matrix. however, it's taking too long to substitute values because the symbolic expressions are very complicated. It takes around 100 seconds for the every substitution and I need at least 10,000 iterations to get a meaningful result.

So, I was wondering whether there is any speedy way to substitute the values. Right now, I'm just substituting values into the top diagonal half of the matrix, which halves the number of substitutions, but it's still taking too long.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a sample of the code you're using and the kind of expressions you'd want to substitute? That might give us a better idea of what we're working with.

Comment: it's an algebraic expression with a few trigonometric functions. I don't know if that helps. I'm not really sure which part of my code would be helpful  answer the question. But maybe the above info helps?

Comment: Why do you use a symbolic library for this? Just translate the expressions to numpy/scipy or write them directly in numpy. If you actually need to use sympy to do some symbolics before the numerics you can just use the `lambdify` function or even print out the expression to a file as a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I completely understand your answer @Krastanov.  I thought I needed to use the symbolic package because what I have is a symbolic expression for the entries of the matrix, i.e. in terms of the variables. And then, I start with a given set of initial values for these coordinates and evaluate the matrix at this point. Then I integrate to find the value of the coordinates at the next time step (I need the inverse of the matrix to do this integration) and then plug these new values in to find the matrix at the next time step. So, I don't understand how to do so using numpy.

Comment: Well, you used the word `timestep` so it seems that you are using a symbolic library to implement a numerical integration algorithm (the Euler algorithm I suppose). numpy has the ability to calculate inverses of matrices. You can define a pythonic function (`def whatever():`) that returns the expression you want in numpy format, without the need for symbolics. And for integration you can use `scipy.integrate` which provides more advanced numerical integration algorithms. It works on matrices/vectors as well as on scalars. You should use symbolic libraries if you want analytical solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I am performing a numerical integration. And I'm using the symbolic library only to find the numerical value of the matrix at each step of integration because I have it in symbolic form. But if I were to use only numpy, how would I do this substitution? Thanks!

Comment: Try using `cse()` on the Matrix to pull out common sub-expressions.